# 3-connected graph and edge contraction

Tags: graph-theory

I have a question on 3-connected graphs:

In the Diestel's book, 5th edition, page 64, it is written:

Every 3-connected graph $G\neq K^4$ has an edge $e$ such that $G/xy$ is again 3-connected.

Here is the beginning of the proof: Suppose there is no such edge $e$. Then, for every edge $xy\in G$, the graph $G/xy$ contains a separator $S$ of at most 2 vertices. Since $\kappa(G)\geq 3$, the contracted vertex $v_{xy}$ of $G/xy$ lies in $S$ and $|S|=2$

> > I really don't see why the vertex $v_{xy}$ lies in $S$. I tried to see what happens if this vertex is not in $S$. Then, we can have $S'=S\cup\{v_{xy}\}$, but what can we do with this set? I don't see why the fact that $\kappa(G)$ implies the vertex is in $S$. Maybe it's simple but I don't see.

Thank you.

Comment: If $v_{xy}\notin S$, then $S$ contains only vertices from $G$, so $G$ also has a 2-separator set, which contradicts the fact that $\kappa(G)\ge 3$.

Comment: OK, i got it. Thank you

Comment: That is, if $S$ is a separator $G/xy$, it's also a separator of $G$, for since $G/xy$ is an induced graph of $G$?

Comment: Yes, when $S$ does not contain $v_{xy}$.